# Is there a substitute for cheese salt?

Tags: salt, cheese-making

I've started to learn how to make cheese and all the recipes call for cheese salt. What is it about this particular salt that makes it different than others? Some of the reading I've done have a few comments that suggest there is no difference between cheese salt and fine table salt. Is there another substitute for cheese salt if for some reason in the future I can't get my hands on any? I'm mostly interested in making hard cheeses that will need to age for 3 to 6 months.

Comment: When I saw this in the HNQ, I assumed that "cheese salt" was some kind of cheese-flavoured salt, like garlic salt only cheesy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cheese salt is just non-iodized salt, generally in flake form; the iodine would interfere with the cultures, and flakes are good for salting surfaces. So kosher salt and flaky sea salt are both essentially the same thing and viable substitutes.

Comment: Sea salt naturally contains iodine. If iodine interferes with cheese cultures, why is sea salt a viable substitute? Is it a question of the iodine *concentration*, or different *kind* of iodides?

Comment: It's the concentration, I believe. Iodized salt has enough added to be a nutritional supplement, effectively.

Comment: Also, from Wikipedia on iodized salt: "An opened package of table salt with iodide may rapidly lose its iodine content through the process of oxidation and iodine sublimation." I suspect that sea salt might lose a fair bit of iodine the same way during production? I'll try to see if I can find actual numbers though.

Answer (score 4):

Cheese salt basically is kosher salt. [Look at this Curd Nerd page about salt](http://curd-nerd.com/cheese-salt-kind-of-salt/) to check out what others say.  Yes, it will make a difference; just buy non-iodized salt - which you should be able to get almost anywhere, methinks.

Comment: My first attempt was a bit of a wreck. I didn't know about Ultra pasteurized milk but I was able to rescue it and came out with a nice ricotta.

Comment: @JasonWhipple you might try connecting with the [Ohio Cheese Guild](http://www.ohiocheeseguild.org/) for resources, and lots more